# Gradle plugin for Tomcat 9.0.34

Tags: java, tomcat, gradle, gradle-plugin, tomcat9

I'm trying to start my app using https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-tomcat-plugin.

My gradle config looks like that:

```
apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.tomcat'

ext.tomcatVersion = '9.0.30'

dependencies {
    // some dependencies

    tomcat "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:$tomcatVersion",
            "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:9.0.0.M6",
            "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:$tomcatVersion",
            "org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:$tomcatVersion",
            "org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-dbcp:$tomcatVersion"
}

tomcat {
    httpProtocol = 'org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Nio2Protocol'
    ajpProtocol  = 'org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpNio2Protocol'
    httpPort = 8088
}
```

With Tomcat version up to `9.0.30` it runs smoothly, but with the latest `9.0.31+` the following exception is thrown (cut for brevity):

```
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1066)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:438)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:468)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat$start$1.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:119)
        at com.bmuschko.gradle.tomcat.embedded.BaseTomcatServerImpl.start(BaseTomcatServerImpl.groovy:53)
        at com.bmuschko.gradle.tomcat.embedded.TomcatServer$start$7.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:119)
        at com.bmuschko.gradle.tomcat.tasks.AbstractTomcatRun.startTomcat(AbstractTomcatRun.groovy:365)
        ...
        at com.bmuschko.gradle.tomcat.tasks.AbstractTomcatRun.validateConfigurationAndStartTomcat(AbstractTomcatRun.groovy:233)
        ...
        at com.bmuschko.gradle.tomcat.tasks.AbstractTomcatRun$_start_closure2.doCall(AbstractTomcatRun.groovy:226)
        at com.bmuschko.gradle.tomcat.tasks.AbstractTomcatRun$_start_closure2.doCall(AbstractTomcatRun.groovy)
        ...
        at com.bmuschko.gradle.tomcat.internal.utils.TomcatThreadContextClassLoader.withClasspath(TomcatThreadContextClassLoader.groovy:30)
        at com.bmuschko.gradle.tomcat.internal.utils.ThreadContextClassLoader$withClasspath.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:135)
        at com.bmuschko.gradle.tomcat.tasks.AbstractTomcatRun.start(AbstractTomcatRun.groovy:225)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        ...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The AJP Connector is configured with secretRequired="true" but the secret attribute is either null or "". This combination is not valid.
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AbstractAjpProtocol.start(AbstractAjpProtocol.java:264)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1063)
```

How to get rid of it? Can this be fixed by configuration change? Is there any tomcat plugin fork which handles it nicely or maybe another gradle plugin for tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
ajpProtocol  = 'org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpNio2Protocol'
```

with

```
ajpProtocol = 'org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Nio2Protocol'
```

This will allow bmuschko to bypass the AJP connector protocol.